# View piaChart decimal values

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I have the following values that I would like to present via piaChart

3.0283506

0.25773194

95.87629

0.83762884

How can I configure the dataLabelFormatString so it will show also values that are less than 1 so the result will look like this:

3.02

0.25

95.8

0.83

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to show the first 4 chars of your values?

In that case you want to use %4.4s in your dataLabelFormatString.

```
    double num1 = 3.0283506;
    double num2 = 0.25773194;
    double num3 = 95.87629;
    double num4 = 0.83762884;

    System.out.format("%4.4s%n", num1);
    System.out.format("%4.4s%n", num2);
    System.out.format("%4.4s%n", num3);
    System.out.format("%4.4s%n", num4);
```

produces:

```
3.02
0.25
95.8
0.83
```

Comment: I guess the chart can present such small values , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to place the decimal format datalabel by using the setting.

rendererOptions: {
                    fill: true,
                    showDataLabels: true,
                    dataLabelFormatString: '%.2f%'
                }